# Output issues with document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write

I am trying to write a javascript that counts the number of negative, zero, and positive numbers in an array. When I run this script it says "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

I don't know how to define document, because it is my understanding that document.write is part of node.js? What is the best way to get it to output the neg, zero, and pos variables?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Function: counter
// Parameter: -3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 29, 30
// Returns the number of each in the array
var input = new Array(-3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 29, 30);
var zero = 0;
var neg = 0;
var pos = 0;

function counter(input, zero, neg, pos)
{
    switch (input)
    {
       case (input < 0):
       neg++;
       break;

       case (input == 0):
       zero++;
       break;

       case (input > 0):
       pos++;
       break;
    } 

return document.write(neg, zero, pos);
}

 counter(input);
```

Comment: makes no sense to do ` return document.write...` And I do not think you want to use document.write in Node.

Comment: try console.log instead

Comment: This is easily solve: don't use document.write more or less... ever.

Comment: What do I use to output the text then? All I have been taught is document.write

Comment: So, following what @gaemaf said, I used console.log but now it just prints out three zeroes. So apparently it isnt running my array through the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cycle on all elements contained in the array, and if you call the function with only one argument I suggest to avoid to define the other three.

The code is:

```
    var input = new Array(-3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 29, 30);
    var zero = 0;
    var neg = 0;
    var pos = 0;

    function counter(input) {
        input.forEach(function(ele) {
            switch (true) {
                case (ele < 0):
                    neg++;
                    break;
                case (ele == 0):
                    zero++;
                    break;
                case (ele > 0):
                    pos++;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    counter(input);

    console.log(neg, zero, pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working using console.log but now the outputs are wrong. My switch doesnt seem to be evaluating the array properly. It prints three zeroes no matter what the value of input is

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Function: counter
// Parameter: -3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 29, 30
// Returns the number of each in the array
var input = new Array(-3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 29, 30);
var zero = 0;
var neg = 0;
var pos = 0;

function counter(input, zero, neg, pos)
{
  switch (input)
  {
     case (input < 0):
            neg ++;
     break;

     case (input == 0):
            zero ++;
     break;

     case (input > 0):
            pos ++;
     break;
    }   
}

counter(input);

console.log(neg, zero, pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is my understanding that document.write is part of node.js?

No, really not. The [`document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document) is part of the DOM interface in browsers.

You probably want to use [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) instead.